# Is it possible to deploy a rails application to Heroku without changing stages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been running into a problem pushing code to Heroku and having stages change that break my application. It works locally, yet when I push to Heroku I notice that the app switches to production stage and breaks.

Is there any way to only use one stage, i.e. develop in my production stage locally? I'm in no need of version history. Alternatively, could I simply push my development stage to Heroku?

Locally, I'm running OSX 10.8.1, Ruby 1.9.3p194, and Rails 3.2.8.

The app is a minimal blog based on what I've been learning and piecing things together. It utilizes SQLite for storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing why your application is breaking when pushed to Heroku, I'm guessing that it's one of a couple issues.

- First, you must be using Postgres for your db, i.e.: `gem 'pg'` in your `Gemfile` at least for the `:production` group.
- Second, assets must be precompiled or a config setting must be changed to allow the assets to compile without initializing the application:

  `rake assets:precompile`

  or

  Add `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to your `config/environments/production.rb` file.

I typically use the `rake assets:precompile` and then add the assets to my git repo, though many will argue (and I'll agree) that adding those files to your repo usually isn't the best of ideas.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a go and answer back.

Comment: Huh. Could I use MySQL, or is it better in your opinion to use Postgres in this situation? - speed wise.

Comment: There are a couple add-ons for MySQL if you want to try them out: https://addons.heroku.com/. Don't let anyone bully you into believing that MySQL or Postgres is faster. They both scale just fine. Make it a matter of preference.

Comment: I second what Chris had to say. If you're running Heroku without any addons though, you're forced to use Postgres, as that's what Heroku provides by default. That said, I've got a production app running on Heroku right now that uses the ClearDB MySQL addon and I haven't had an issue with db performance.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bad idea to use just one environment. Don't do it.

Your local/development and production environments may have differences, which is why you use 2 different environments, so you can capture those in the config files.  Lots of caching, compiling assets,  and debugging only occur in dev or prod, and you want them to behave differently.

Instead, you need to debug what is different in prod and dev (heroku and local) and change your app to account for those differences.

For example, Heroku does not support sqlite - it uses postgres by default.

So you need to have sqlite in the Gemfile for development, and the pg gem for production, or (I strongly recommend) move to using postgres in development as well (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-do-i-use-sqlite3-for-development).

If you choose to continue with sqlite in development, your Gemfile should look like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give production mode a try on your local machine, start the server like so:

```
rails server -e production
```

Hopefully that will let you catch some of the gotchas before pushing to Heroku.

Andrew's answer is key. There is less caching and such in development mode for your convenience. Production mode runs more efficiently but would be a major pain to develop on. (You would constantly need to reload caches and recompile assets, for example.) You don't want to run development mode in production because your app would run very sluggishly.

Hopefully that gives you an idea of the trade-offs between running one environment over the other. The factors in the trade-off are mainly a matter of development convenience vs. performance.

Comment: Ah. That actually makes a lot of sense. Thanks!